# Get user domain in windows in Flutter

Tags: flutter, windows

I know how to get username of Windows’ user in Flutter for Windows using win32 for Flutter. But I cannot find a way to get user domain? Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean the "domain of the connected user" ? If so, you can check in the environment variables for "USERDOMAIN".

Comment: Yes the domain of user logged in to windows. In Python code, we can use the userdomain variable but I don’t see it in Flutter. In the answer below, you can get username but not user domain. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73979743/flutter-desktop-how-to-get-windows-user-profile-name

Answer (score 0):

On windows, the user's domain is stored in an environment variable called USERDOMAIN.

You can fetch environment variables by using [Platform.environment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform/environment.html).

```
import 'dart:io';
...
String userDomain = Platform.environment['USERDOMAIN'];
```